# Ionic 4 - Firebase - Storage not sending data to realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm uploading images to Firebase storage, and then i want them to go to the real time database, this code was working in ionic v3, but now it seems something is wrong since the data goes to the storage but not to the database.

```
    createPost(picture: string): Promise<any> {

        firebase.storage().ref('/home/')
            .child('picture.jpg')
            .putString(picture, 'base64', { contentType: 'image/jpg' })
            .then((savedPicture) => {
                firebase.database().ref('Home').push({
                    picture: savedPicture.downloadURL
                }).then(() => {
                    alert('Sucess');
                    this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/home');
                })
            });
        return
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The download URL of the new upload is no longer available as `savedPicture.downloadURL`. You will need call `getDownloadURL()` on the storage reference after the upload completes:

```
let ref = firebase.storage().ref('/home/').child('picture.jpg');
 ref.putString(picture, 'base64', { contentType: 'image/jpg' })
    .then((savedPicture) => {
        ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
          firebase.database().ref('Home').push({
            picture: url
          }).then(() => {
            alert('Sucess');
            this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/home');
          })
        })
    });
```

Also see:

- The [documentation on downloading a file via its URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url)
- The [documentation on monitoring upload progress](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress)